# SELECT another value based on the existing result - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following requirement to generate a specific output.

Table e_t_d,

```
b_c e_no    r_no    o_b
A   XL25631 BC25896 
B   BC25896 XL25631 X0001
A   RT85962 EW89656 L0002
B   EW89656 RT85962 
A   BF12345         X0001
A   BD456321        X0001
A   DF85962         X0001
A   WS25641         X0001

SELECT t1.a_d,
       (CASE
            WHEN t1.o_b IS NULL AND t1.b_c = 'B'
            THEN
                (SELECT t1.o_b
                   FROM e_t_d t1
                  WHERE t1.e_no = t1.r_no AND t1.b_c = 'A')
            WHEN t1.o_b IS NULL AND t1.b_c = 'A'
            THEN
                (SELECT t1.o_b
                   FROM e_t_d t1
                  WHERE t1.e_no = t1.r_no AND t1.b_c = 'B')
            ELSE
                t1.o_b
        END)
           AS reference_no
  FROM e_t_d t1
 WHERE t1.b_c IN ('A', 'B') AND t1.d_id IN ('20', '35')
       AND ( (t1.a_d >= '1-Apr-2018' AND t1.a_d <= '15-Apr-2018')
            OR (t1.a_r >= '1-Apr-2018' AND t1.a_r <= '15-Apr-2018'))
```

Using the above query, what I'm trying to achieve is the following.

Following are the conditions I'm trying to satisfy.

1. if o_b column contains a value take it
2. if the o_b column is empty and the r_no contains a value then take the o_b value where the o_b=b_c and b_c != A or vise versa.

The above query I have does not give me the values for the second condition.

r_no column contains many types of number and I have only included few, its same for the o_b column as well.

The result I'm trying to take is the following.

```
b_c e_no    r_no    o_b
B   BC25896 XL25631 X0001
A   RT85962 EW89656 L0002
A   BF12345         X0001
A   BD456321        X0001
A   DF85962         X0001
A   WS25641         X0001
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the table you defined as `The result I'm trying to take is the following` reports exactly the rows having `o_b IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Hi, Its not like that. There can be empty one's as well. Mistakenly I have not included in the question. There may be rows which do not have the o_b value but if it has the r_no then only it should go an check the other parameters. Hope its clear now. The result set Im working with is pretty large hence I cannot copy paste all here.